# How to return this state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a function InternetStatus() like below. I call this function in the  render() through console.log but it still show undefined? How do i fix it? Thank you!

```
function InternetStatus() {

  NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
    return (state.isConnected)
  });

}
```

```
render() {
    console.log(InternetStatus())    
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>
            hello
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetInfo.fetch()` is an async function which means the the `InternetStatus` function will resume execution and in the code above it is not returning anything hence you are getting undefined. One way to handle is to chain promises.

```
function InternetStatus() {

  return NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
    return (state.isConnected)
  });
}
```

```
render() {
    InternetStatus().then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })    
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>
            hello
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
  }
}
```

If you mean to use api response on the UI, then you need to force a state change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It worked for me !
I have a further questions can I use this in if()?
like below
`if (InternetStatus()) 
if (!InternetStatus()) `
How can I get the result?

Comment: Sorry I'm rookie for this.

Comment: No, you cannot. Every async function has to be executed with a `.then()`
You could explore `async/await` if you want a cleaner code.

Comment: Thank you very I set state to handle the result.It worked for me:)